# Prove that tan15a- tan10a-tan5a= tan 15a +tan 10a +tan 5a

Tags: trigonometry

![enter image description here]9(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oND8J.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your equation we have
$$2\tan(10a)+2\tan(5a)=0$$ and this is equivalent to
$$\sec(10a)\sec(5a)\sin(15a)=0$$
How can this be? What is $a$?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean $$\tan15a-\tan10a-\tan5a=\tan5a\tan15a\tan10a$$
so we need to prove that 
$$\tan15a-\tan10a=\tan5a(1+\tan15a\tan10a)$$ or
$$\frac{\tan15a-\tan10a}{1+\tan15a\tan10a}=\tan5a,$$
which is obvious.